# functionCallOnClose not working in JQuery DOMWindow plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/VtNaU/

'functionCallOnOpen' seems to work fine but 'functionCallOnClose' (the one I actually want to use) doesn't seem to work. I've also tried .closeDOMWindow click() but that only is called if the close button is clicked - not if the outside area is clicked (which also closes the window).
Here's the plugin's source code:
http://swip.codylindley.com/jquery.DOMWindow.js

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://swip.codylindley.com/jquery.DOMWindow.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#test1').click(function(event) {
    $.openDOMWindow({ 
        functionCallOnOpen: function () { 
            alert("opening");
        },      
        functionCallOnClose: function () { 
            alert("closing");
        },
        height:100, 
        width:200,
        windowSourceID:'#theWindow'
    }); 
});
});
</script>
<button id="test1">Open Window</button>

<div style="display:none;" id="theWindow"> 
<h1>Test</h1>
<button class="closeDOMWindow">Close</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This script has a few problems but you can avoid those paths in the script by using jQuery to find a close function to your button:

http://jsfiddle.net/cybermonk/Zd78c/

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks it is working better but there is a new problem.... http://jsfiddle.net/eJRYf/2/ if you click the close button it repeatedly shows the "closing" alert - one time for each time you've closed the window. So if the window has already been closed 10 times (either by clicking "close" or clicking outside the window) the "closing" alert appears 11 times after you click "close". Edited DOMWindow script: http://sky-walker.net/temp/test/jquery.DOMWindow-new.js

Comment: Hi sorry I don't know what you mean when you say "Try rolling back the changes within ...."
Also in that jsfiddle it doesn't detect if the window is closed if you click outside of the window...

Comment: Updated my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cybermonk/Zd78c/ , the problem still exists but my fiddle avoids that path (each time you close it accumulates the call on close functions). Also open the console so you can see the log statements...

Comment: Sorry I wanted the DOMWindow.js script to be independent so that I can easily reuse it.....